# React redux current user param gets too late to use

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

The problem lays in the code below

```
class GroupsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      groups: [],
    }
  }

  async fetchGroups (){
    fetchGroupsFirebase().then((res) => {this.setState({groups:res})})
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    await this.fetchGroups();
    
  }
  
  render(){}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  user: selectCurrentUser
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupsPage);
```

As you see , i call fetchGroups to get some data from firebase, it works allright but i want to get specific data for my current user, my problem is that i can't send de currentUser id as a param to the fetchGroupsFirebase functions, because at the time of the call, this.props.user is still null , and it gets the value from mapStateToProps only after the component mounted.

I hope that i am clear enough, i know it is messy
TLDR: I need the user id but when i get it it's too late

Comment: If you want to load specific users data that means you have to either render this component after the current user is loaded or inside the GroupsPage component check for current user props changes in componentDidUpdate function and when its not empty load the groups specific to user. I hope this make sense

Comment: It makes sense, but can you tell me how to render the component after current user is loaded? @Sohel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you would need to do is to first check if the user prop is available right after the mount - if not skip the api call and wait untill the user prop gets updated using componentDidUpdate lifecycle method.
This way, your api call will be made as soon as the user prop gets injected to the component.

```js
class GroupsPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      groups: [],
    };
  }

  async fetchGroups(id) {
    fetchGroupsFirebase(id).then((res) => {
      this.setState({ groups: res });
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.user) {
      await this.fetchGroups(this.props.user);
    }
  }

  async componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.user && this.props.user !== prevProps.user) {
      await this.fetchGroups(this.props.user);
    }
  }

  render() {}
}

const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  user: selectCurrentUser,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GroupsPage);
```